# utf8 encoding lost after tokenising using NLTK and Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding, nltk

I ran into an interesting problem when attempting to tokenise a french text using nltk (version 3.1, python 2.7). Here is the code snippet I am using.

```
#python 2.7

from __future__ import division
import nltk, re, pprint

f= open('test.txt')

raw = f.read()
print "got it!"
print type(raw)

ucoderaw=raw.decode('utf-8')
print ucoderaw

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(ucoderaw)
print type(tokens)
words = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
print type(words)
vocab = sorted(set(words))
print "Tokens"
```

The document contains a french text:

> J'ai lieu de croire que Mr. de Voltaire ne sera pas fâché de voir que
>   son Manuscrit, qu'il a intitulé *Abrégé de l'Histoire Universelle
>   depuis Charlemagne jusqu'à Charles-Quint*, et qu'il dit être entre les
>   mains de trente Particuliers, soit tombé entre les miennes. Il sait
>   qu'il m'en avait flatté dès l'année 1742, à l'occasion de son Siècle
>   de Louis XIV, auquel je ne renonçai en 1750, que parce qu'il me dit
>   alors à Postdam, où j'étais, qu'il l'imprimait lui-même à ses propres
>   dépens. Ainsi il ne s'agit ici que de dire comment cet Abrégé m'est
>   tombé entre les mains, le voici.
>
> À mon retour de Paris, en Juin de cette année 1753, je m'arrêtai à
>   Bruxelles, où j'eus l'honneur de voir une Personne de mérite, qui en
>   étant le possesseur me le fit voir, et m'en fit aussi tout l'éloge
>   imaginable, de même que l'histoire du Manuscrit, et de tout ce qui
>   s'était passé à l'occasion d'un *Avertissement* qui se trouve inséré
>   dans le
>   *second Volume du mois de Juin 1752 du Mercure de France*, et répété dans l'*Épilogueur du 31 Juillet de la même année*, avec la Réponse
>   que l'on y a faite, et qui se trouve dans le même *Épilogueur du 7
>   Août suivant*: toutes choses inutiles à relever ici, mais qui m'ont
>   ensuite déterminé à acheter des mains de ce Galant-Homme le Manuscrit
>   après avoir été offert à l'Auteur, bien persuadé d'ailleurs qu'il
>   était effectivement de Mr. de Voltaire; son génie, son style, et
>   surtout son orthographe s'y trouvant partout. J'ai changé cette
>   dernière, parce qu'il est notoire que le Public a toutes les peines du
>   monde à s'y accoutumer; et c'est ce que l'Auteur est prié de vouloir
>   bien excuser.[1]
>
> Je dois encore faire remarquer que par la dernière période de ce
>   Livre, il paraît qu'elle fait la clôture de cet Abrégé, qui finit à
>   *Charles VII Roi de France*, au lieu que l'Auteur la promet par son Titre jusqu'à l'*Empereur Charles-Quint*. Ainsi il est à présumer que
>   ce qui devrait suivre, est cette partie différente d'Histoire qui
>   concerne *les Arts*, qu'il serait à souhaiter que Mr. de Voltaire
>   retrouvât, ou, pour mieux dire, qu'il voulût bien refaire, et la
>   pousser jusqu'au *Siècle de Louis XIV*, afin de remplir son plan, et
>   de nous donner ainsi une suite d'Histoire qui ferait grand plaisir au
>   Public et aux Libraires.

When I attempt to tokenise that text using `tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(ucoderaw)`

and then subsequently print out the tokens using `sorted(set(words))`

I get output with broken utf-8 encoding:

> u'autant', u'author', u'autres', u'aux', u'available', u'avait',
>   u'avant', u'avec', u'avertissement', u'avoir', u'avons', u'away',
>   u'ayant', u'barbare', u'beaucoup', u'biblioth\xe8que', u'bien',
>   u'bnf/gallica', u'bornais', u'bruxelles', u'but', u'by', u"c'est",
>   u'capet', u'carri\xe8re', u'ce', u'cela', u'ces', u'cet', u'cette',
>   u'ceux', u'chang\xe9', u'chaos', u'character', u'charger',
>   u'charlemagne', u'charlequint', u'charles-quint_', u'chartes',
>   u'chez', u'chine', u'choses', u'chronologie', u'chronologiques',
>   u'chr\xe9tienne', u'cl\xf4ture'

where the correct output should include accents i.e. **bibliothèque** and not **biblioth\xe8que**

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this, short of saving the output to a file and writing another program to replace  \xe8 with è and so on and so forth.

Is there a simpler method?

**EDIT:** Not the cleanest solution, however I found that by tokenising and then saving that output to a file with the correct encoding I do (largely get the output required):

```
#python 2.7

#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division
import nltk, re, pprint

f= open('test.txt')

raw = f.read()


print "got it!"

#print raw

print type(raw)

#encode as utf8 before moving on.
ucoderaw=raw.decode('utf-8')

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(ucoderaw)

print type(tokens)

words = [w.lower() for w in tokens]

print type(words)

vocab = sorted(set(words))

print "encoded raw input is"
print ucoderaw


#                 GET TOKENS

print vocab
#write to file with correct encoding to "fix" the problem
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

print len(vocab)
for words in vocab:
    output_file.write(words.encode('utf-8') + "\n")
```

Comment: Short answer: Use `python3` =) Longer answer: don't use `open`, use `io.open('filename.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')` Better answer: see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and then still use `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Then try to use `Python3` instead of `Python2` for text processing, it makes your life a lot easier =)

Finally, regardless of Py3 or Py2, using `io.open` instead of `open` is a good practice so that your code works across both Py3 and Py2:

```
import io
from collections import Counter
import nltk

# Try to open files within a context, see 
# https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ and 
# http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm
with io.open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    word_counts = Counter(word_tokenize(fin.read()))
    # List of top most common words.
    print word_counts.most_common()
    # Sorted by counts
    print word_counts.most_common(len(word_counts))
    # Sorted alphabetically
    print sorted(word_counts.keys())
```